# How to prove that if $P(A|B) > P(A) > 0$, then $P(A^ \complement| B) < P(A^ \complement)$?

Tags: statistics, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

How do I prove that if $P(A|B) > P(A) > 0$, then $P(A^ \complement| B) < P(A^ \complement)$?

So far, I'm thinking that I need to use the definition:
P(A$\cap B^\complement$) + P($A \cap B$) = P(A)
and/or the conditional probability theorem but can't quite work out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb{P}(A^c\mid B)\geq \mathbb{P}(A^c)$. Then
$$ 1=\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)+\mathbb{P}(A^c\mid B)>\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(A^c)=1$$
which is absurd.